# Searching for items within beautifulsoup when the class name appears in more than one place

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

My issue is with `BeautifulSoup` and Python.  I am trying to scrape a website but the issue is that the `div` and class name appear in multiple spots throughout the html so when I scrape it only show the first match of each class. Here is an example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib2

url= 'http://www.thinkgeek.com/interests/marvel/?icpg=HP_BrandLogos_Top_Color_Marvel'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())

for a in soup.findAll("div",{"class": "footer-link-column"}):
    print a.a.contents[0]
```

If I run that, it returns only the first cleaned html of each section.  Help would be appreciated.  (This site was only an example, the real site has the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to use findall:

```
for a in soup.findAll("div",{"class": "footer-link-column"}):
    print("\n".join([a.text.strip() for a in a.find_all("a")]))
print(" ")



Returns & Exchanges
Order Status
Shipping
Accounts
Ordering
Size Charts
Gift Options
Gift Certificates
International Orders
Privacy & Security
Terms of Use
Live Chat

About Us
Jobs
Our Blog
Press
Contact Us
Newsletter
Volume Purchases
Affiliates
Sitemap

Account
Order Management
GeekPoints
Forgot Password
Wish Lists
Return Requests
Address Book
Submit Action Shot
Submit a T-Shirt Design
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and loop over sections and links separately:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.thinkgeek.com/interests/marvel/?icpg=HP_BrandLogos_Top_Color_Marvel'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for section in soup.select("div.footer-link-column"):
    section_name = section.h4.get_text(strip=True)
    print section_name
    print
    for item in section('a'):
        print item.get_text(strip=True)
    print "----"
```

Prints:

```
Customer Service

Returns & Exchanges
Order Status
Shipping
Accounts
Ordering
Size Charts
Gift Options
Gift Certificates
International Orders
Privacy & Security
Terms of Use
Live Chat
----
About ThinkGeek

About Us
Jobs
Our Blog
Press
Contact Us
Newsletter
Volume Purchases
Affiliates
Sitemap
----
Come to the "not-so-dark" side

Account
Order Management
GeekPoints
Forgot Password
Wish Lists
Return Requests
Address Book
Submit Action Shot
Submit a T-Shirt Design
----
```

Comment: Thank you!  I will play around with those.